# Value_counts() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm running the code below the meet the outlined object but am getting an error I'm not sure how to fix.

```
class variableTreatment():
         def drop_zero_car_col(self, df):
            numerical = list(df._get_numeric_data().columns)
            categorical = list(set(df.columns).difference(set(numerical)))
            ls = []
            for i in categorical:
                d = dict(i.value_counts())
                if len(d)==1:
                    ls.append(i)
            df.drop(ls,axis=1,inplace=True)
            return(df)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler,LabelEncoder
df = pd.read_excel('CKD.xlsx')

VT = variableTreatment()

VT

VT.drop_zero_car_col(df).head()
```

To perform this:
Drops categorical columns with same levels, such as a column with all 'yes' values

Inputs:
1. Dataframe df: Pandas dataframe

Outputs:
1. Dataframe df with dropped columns (if no columns are dropped, you will return the same dataframe)

But I'm getting this error:

````
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e04a1da339fd> in <module>
----> 1 VT.drop_zero_car_col(df).head()

<ipython-input-3-64cf5361fc06> in drop_zero_car_col(self, df)
     54         ls = []
     55         for i in categorical:
---> 56             d = dict(i.value_counts())
     57             if len(d)==1:
     58                 ls.append(i)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value_counts'```
````

Comment: Why you are using series value_counts method on strings

Comment: What is the purpose of the class here? I’m seeing a lot of strange operations, can you share more of your code and some data? See: [mcve].

Comment: Kapil - A friend was helping me and as we were researching we thought this was the correct way to go about it. How would you recommend doing it? 
Alexander- There are a range of other functions under this class that don’t relate to this function. The class does also represent VT. Ill be able to post the data first thing tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop non-numerical columns with same values in dataframe you can change your function like below:

```
class variableTreatment():
         def drop_zero_car_col(self, df):
            # selecting numerical columns without accessing private method
            numerical = list(df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns)
            categorical = list(set(df.columns).difference(set(numerical)))
            # after above line categorical will have only non numeric columns
            ls = []
            for i in categorical:
                # value_counts will return series containing count of non unique values 
                d = df[i].value_counts()    
                # if series length is 1 then it means there is only one value in column that is duplicated across all rows so this columns should be dopped                
                if len(d)==1:
                    ls.append(i)
            df.drop(ls,axis=1,inplace=True)
            return(df)
```